# Google Play Developer API purchases.subscriptions doesn't return emailAddress field

Tags: ionic-framework, in-app-purchase, google-play-developer-api, google-play-billing

I'm integrating with Google Play Developer API (https://developers.google.com/android-publisher). To be more specific I'm trying to get informations about a specific subscription (https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions/get).

Well I'm already getting informations about a subscription with the `subscriptionId` and `purchaseToken`. The problem is that some fields are not being returned in response. One of these field is `emailAddress` that importante for my usage context. I'm getting a response like the one shown below.

```json
{
    "startTimeMillis": "1631112305355",
    "expiryTimeMillis": "1638981894973",
    "autoRenewing": true,
    "priceCurrencyCode": "BRL",
    "priceAmountMicros": "39990000",
    "countryCode": "BR",
    "developerPayload": "",
    "paymentState": 1,
    "orderId": "GPA.9999-5849-9341-89139",
    "acknowledgementState": 1,
    "kind": "androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase"
}
```

From the docs about `emailAddress` we have *The email address of the user when the subscription was purchased. Only present for purchases made with 'Subscribe with Google'.*

But what is `Subscribe with Google`? Isn't Google Play Billing in this category? My purchases are made on an Android mobile app with Play Billing.

Thanks any help.

Comment: I think 'Subscribe with Google' means got permission for publish user e-mail. So this field will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe with Google is a completely different thing that Google offers or at least used to offer, these are not normal subscriptions, for normal subs you do not get the users email.

> Subscribe with Google lets you buy a subscription, using your Google
> account, on participating news sites. Select the publisher offer you’d
> like to buy, click “Subscribe,” and you’re done. You’ll automatically
> be signed in to the site, and you can pay–securely and privately—with
> any credit card you’ve used with Google in the past.

https://blog.google/outreach-initiatives/google-news-initiative/introducing-subscribe-google/